# XPath Query for URL Extraction

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, extract, data-extraction

I need to extract `http://site.ru/` from this code:

```
<div class="one">
<dl>
<dt class="two">
<span class="name">Site</span>
</dt>
<dd class="three">
<span class="js-pseudo-link" data-url="rAnDoMlEtTeRsAnDnUmBeRs" style>
<a href="http://site.ru/" class rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style> http://site.ru/ </a>
</span>
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

I use this XPath query: `//div//dl//dd//span//a/@href`

But it doesn't work. It doesn't return anything.
I'm a newbie in XPath.

Comment: Depending on the site, you may not be allowed to do so because the page is generated after loading. What's the website?

Comment: https://msk.spravker.ru/avtoservisy-avtotehcentry/

Comment: Unfortunately, the data source you are looking for is an empty span node (class `js-pseudo-link`). The data-url is the base64 encoded link you want. This node only gets populated after loading. ImportXML for some reason ignores nodes with no text and there's no way to get it not to do that. To get around this, looks like you'll have to write an apps script that can handle empty nodes or just gets the raw HTML code and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the data source you are looking for is an empty span node (class `js-pseudo-link`). The `data-url` attribute has the base64 encoded link you want. This node only gets populated after loading. `ImportXML` for some reason ignores nodes with no text and there's no way to get it not to do that. To get around this, looks like you'll have to write an apps script that can handle empty nodes or just gets the raw HTML code and parse it.